# Margin 0 auto not working for me in IE 9

Tags: css

I am working with some css and I spent about 3 hours on figuring out why margin 0 auto not working in IE

The link is

```
stage.media-carrier.de/home/box/10
```

When i open it in firefox, chrome etc it works fine the content is in the center but in IE everything else is fine but the content does not go to the center of page

Any ideas __?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the style tag on the top on your page in the head. The doctype must be the first element on the page to prevent errors.
Because of that IE runs the page in quirks-mode.

Comment: sorry didn't get your point about which style tag you are talking about ?

Comment: The first element in your html code is a style tag with css styles for the page. This tag including the styles has to be moved into the head tag of the code.

Comment: I dont think so All my styles are in the head tag :(

Comment: I've re-checked it. You have definitely the style for for .error over your doctype. View the source of the page.